# translate string with YandexAPI in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-2, yandex-api

I want to translate googleMap Api result for location address to Persian. i'm using YandexApi for translate address. separate address components with "،" and pass this array to for api. my problem is after every service call my userInterface updated. how can solve this problem.
 for example when I pass this array to method:["road","avenue"] 
 address label text update after every translate response
first text for label = "جاده"
last text for label = "جاده ، خیابان"
there is my code:

```
func translateText(text:[String],closure:@escaping ((_ success:String?,_ error:Error?) -> Void)) {

    var translateString: String = ""
    var responseError: Error?
    for item in text {
      myGroup.enter()
    let urlString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20171105T134956Z.795c7a0141d3061b.dc25bae76fa5740b2cdecb02396644dea58edd24&text=\(item)&lang=fa&format=plain&options=1"
    if let allowString = Utilities.shareInstance.getQueryAllowedString(url: urlString) {
      if let url = URL(string:allowString){
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
          guard let responseData = response.data else {
            return
          }
          do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
            if let res = json as? [String:Any] {
              if let code = res["code"] as? Int {
                if code == 200 {
                  if let textArr = res["text"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    let flattArr = Utilities.shareInstance.flatStringMapArray(textArr)
                    if flattArr.count > 0 {
                      translateString += " ، " + flattArr[0]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }catch {
            responseError = error
          }
          self.myGroup.leave()
          closure(translateString, responseError)
        }
      }
    }
   }
  } 

 private func translatingAddressArrayForChecking(address:[String])  {

    var addressString = ""
    let addressComponent = address
    if addressComponent.count > 0 {
      YandexTranslateAPI.shateInstance.translateText(text: addressComponent, closure:{ success,_ in
        if let res = success {
          addressString = res
          OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.layoutActivity(start: false)
            if self.searchState == .Origin && self.destinationButton.isHidden == false{

              if let selectOrigin = self.originSelectedCity {
                if let city = selectOrigin.city_title {
                  if addressString.contains(city) {
                    self.originAddressLabel.text = addressString
                    if let location = self.startCoordinate {
                    self.setOrigin(location: location)

                    }
                  }else {
                    self.CreateCustomTopField(text: "wrong city", color: Constants.ERROR_COLOR)
                  }
                }
              }

            }else if self.searchState == .Destination || self.destinationButton.isHidden == true  {
              if let selectOrigin = self.destinationSelectedCity {
                if let city = selectOrigin.city_title {
                  if addressString.contains(city) {
                    self.destinationAddressLabel.text = addressString
                    if let location = self.endCoordinate {
                      self.setDestination(location: location)
                    }
                  }else {
                    self.CreateCustomTopField(text: "wrong city", color: Constants.ERROR_COLOR)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })

    }
```

addresses label text update multiple with array component.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem you are facing in more detail? I understand what's happening in your code but I really don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @frozencure I edit my question I hope it's clear